# Unable to execute where statement in Kxb

Tags: database, kdb

I am having a hard time running a simple where statement. I am unable to use operators with the WHERE statement and unable to execute the WHERE statement altogether.

Here is the statement I am trying to print out:

```
select col1 from table1 where (col1>88685444)
```

My table name is table1.

I have followed the examples in the documentation and am I bit confused why my query is failing.

Any help would be great!

Edit: When I am running 10#table1:

```
x date    col1        col2           col3         col4            col5..
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
0 12/1/05 88685444 1241.878327     6.350940424    1241.878327   6.350940424 

1 1/1/06  90347817 1267.009556     6.266897859    1267.009556   6.266897859 

2 2/1/06  88705352 1287.222848     6.257696443    1287.222848   6.257696443 

3 3/1/06  89992045 1295.283641     6.394247159    1295.283641   6.394247159 

4 4/1/06  88472932 1292.344184     6.611036277    1292.344184   6.611036277 

5 5/1/06  86654928 1282.237872     6.78018308     1282.237872   6.78018308  

6 6/1/06  86272834 1270.709445     6.812335672    1270.709445   6.812335672 

7 7/1/06  86052243 1266.915205     6.729645289    1266.915205   6.729645289 

8 8/1/06  88192019 1281.385697     6.591521503    1281.385697   6.591521503 

9 9/1/06  87901469 1317.846147     6.454615746    1317.846147   6.454615746
```

Answer (score 3):

From the syntax alone I don't see any problem. Can you provide the meta of the table and the associated error? Please be in mind providing the sample data (simply do a `10#table1` ) will help diagnosis (This should be a comment but I don't have enough reputation :( )

Comment: As mentioned by Davis - can you also provide the output of `meta table1`. It's possible that your col1 is not of a numeric datatype (perhaps it's a string type?). You can't do numerical comparisons if the datatype is not numerical